# Accessing the third level inside a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to list out all the elements inside an array and [as you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/xcEa9/1/) Company has three levels, but I've only written the script to print the output until two levels. How do I access the third level? What should be the array that I should be using inside the third `for loop`?

Comment: [We need to go deeper](http://archive.4chon.net/new/1934112/src_1334719344096.jpg)

Comment: Im confused about the array name that I should be using in the third level.. It gets a bit long n dirty when I get in to the third level

Comment: @dda: I haven't seen any question for about 2 hours that you haven't beautified. Nice job! ;-)

Comment: Which means we look at the same questions. I ignore plenty :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is recursion.

Here is a fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEmf9/

```
function generateEntity(obj) {
    var html = [];

    var name = obj.entity;
    html.push('<li>');
    html.push(name);
    html.push('</li>');
    var arrayName = name.replace(/\s/gi, '_');
    if (obj[arrayName] == undefined) {
        return html.join('');
    }

    var entity = obj[arrayName];
    for (var i = 0; i < entity.length; i++) {
        html.push('<ul>');
        html.push(generateEntity(entity[i]));
        html.push('</ul>');
    }
    return html.join('');
}
```

Comment: Interesting - a 49 minute-old question and the first two answers come in 8 seconds apart. :)  +1 to you for the cleaner version.

Comment: Funny.  I would have finished it a couple minutes ago, but I just couldn't leave that `+=` code in. Probably a touch of OCD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I knew how to do this recursively... bt I wanted to know if I had fixed depth of three.. How am I gonna use the for loop.. How am I gonna access  the third level of entities?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not need a special technique for accessing the third level.  You need to write a recursive tree walking function so that you can render a tree of *any depth*.

I've done a quick patch of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/xcEa9/6/

Once you get things working as you like, you can work on forming your html.  Your repeated string concatenation using `+=` is known to be extremely inefficient, but that is outside the scope of this question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I knew how to do this recursively... bt I wanted to know if I had fixed depth of three.. How am I gonna use the for loop.. How am I gonna access the third level of entities?

Comment: thanks.. I know its not recomended... I wanted to know how it can be done If I went this way.. I have used recursion in the proper program.. bt this question was out of curiousity..